# 'Series' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to run the following

```
df['ln_returns'] = np.log(df['Close_mid']/df['Close_mid'](1))
```

I get the error

```
'Series' object is not callable
```

When checking df.dtypes i get:

```
0
Close_mid      float64
Close_large    float64
Close_small    float64
dtype: object
```

And when checking

```
print(type(df.Close_mid))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How do I solve this ambiguity?
I'm trying to calculate the logarithmic change between to periods

Comment: What do you think `df['Close_mid'](1)` does?

Comment: I believe that it shifts to the second row so that it is t / t_1

Comment: What are you trying to get with `df['Close_mid'](1)`? This is the reason you are receiving this error. `df['Close_mid']` returns a `pd.Series` and you are trying to call it with `1` as an argument.

Comment: What you want is `df['ln_returns'] = np.log(df['Close_mid']/df['Close_mid'].shift(1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of this error is that you wrote `df['Close_mid'](1)`.
In this case *Pandas* acts as follows:

- gets `df['Close_mid']` (a column of your DataFrame),
- tries to **call** it, passing a single parameter (*1*).

If you want to divide each element of this column by its **first element**, write:

```
df['Close_mid']/df['Close_mid'].iloc[0]
```

(note that in a *Series* the numeration of elements starts just from *0*).

If you want to refer to the **previous/next** element, use *shift()*.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help, works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a Series of float64 type values. There is no ambiguity.

`df['Close_mid']` is a Series and is not callable. Trying to call it like so `df['Close_mid'](1)` raises the error.
Maybe you can elaborate on what you are trying to do with calling with `(1)`.

Comment: I see, I'm trying to calculate the logarithmic change between to periods

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying by adding "(1)"?

Try this:

```
df['ln_returns'] = np.log(df['Close_mid']/df['Close_mid'])
```

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the logarithmic change between to periods so by adding (1) I'm trying to divide by previous period